# How to display object on a new row when there is no more space on the previus row

Tags: android

Is there a way to display all object in a row, until that row can contain them (depending on the screen size), and then display the others object on a new row?

What layout should I use?

Answer (score 0):

Try GridLayout, Here is a tutorial.
[GridLayout](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/11/new-layout-widgets-space-and-gridlayout.html)